# Meaning of the phrase "at range" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology

It is from this [article](https://www.bbc.com/sport/boxing/47871481).

> "He is happy to be **at range** but anyone who gets in there and thinks 'let's have it', they bring out a different Lomachenko. The man is a serious body puncher. Not many people talk about it but he has taken people out that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of "at range" typically means separated by a (contextually-appropriate) significant distance.

I am not an expert in boxing, but I think two sentences help set the context

> Lomachenko boasts graceful feet, honed through his mastery of Ukrainian dance. But he is far from just a mover and his last win [...] showcased an 11th-round attack which ranks as one of the most relentless in recent history.

The implication seems to be that he is skillful at keeping his opponents at a distance, but if the opponents get close he's able to defeat them with close-up "body punches" too.